# bags to tuples in pig

Tags: apache-pig, etl

I have four columns A,B,C,D
where column D has all the values same(eg:'d')
Data is

```
A,B,C,D
1,b,1,d
2,x,3,d
3,y,3,d
```

I want to find the median on C and store under column `Median`.Rest of  A,B,C,D should be as usual.
1)performed group on D
2)found median on C using apache fu package(http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/getting-started.html).

I want

```
A,B,C,D,Median
1,b,1,d,3
2,x,3,d,3
3,y,3,d,3
```

but i get

```
{A: {(A: long)},B: {(B: chararray)},C: {(C: long)},D: {(B: chararray)},Median: (quantile_0_5: double),}
```

I want all that bags to be removed and be used as tuples.
Can somebody suggest something to get desired output?

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [BagToTuple](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html) UDF. It takes a Bag and transform it to a Tuple, so you are going to have to call it once for each of your bags (each of your columns). The output of this will give you a tuple for each of the columns, instead of a tuple for the whole row, which I guess it's not what you want, so flatten the output of `BagToTuple`:

```
input_data = load 'input' using PigStorage(',') as (A: bag{(a: long)}, B: bag{(b: chararray)}, C: bag{(c: long)}, D: bag{(d: chararray)}, Median: bag{(median: double)});
dump input_data;

({(1)},{(b)},{(1)},{(d)},{(3.0)})
({(2)},{(x)},{(3)},{(d)},{(3.0)})
({(3)},{(y)},{(3)},{(d)},{(3.0)})

output = foreach input_data generate FLATTEN(BagToTuple($0)), 
                       FLATTEN(BagToTuple($1)), 
                       FLATTEN(BagToTuple($2)), 
                       FLATTEN(BagToTuple($3)), 
                       FLATTEN(BagToTuple($4));

dump output;

(1,b,1,d,3.0)
(2,x,3,d,3.0)
(3,y,3,d,3.0)
```